# Where are Typesafe Activator downloaded files and where is Scala installed? Macbook OSX

Tags: macos, scala, typesafe-activator

I am new to scala and use Macbook for short time and yesterday I downloaded Typesafe Activator, installed it and executed command: activator and activator ui

Then, many files has been downloaded but I wonder: ***where are they?***

I am searching for, for example, Scala files but can find it.. Or they were not downloaded at all?

I have done the research but found nothing

will appreciate your help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

If you need system global `scala` and `sbt` binaries, you can use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) like this:
`brew install scala` and/or `brew install sbt`. 
Don't forget to `brew update` and `brew doctor` before :)

Activator itself just downloads `jar` and then runs it via OS X's preinstalled `java`, so no "scala files" was downloaded :)

After downloading activator you can create template projects via `activator new [project-name] [template-name]`, list of available templates is available either in Activator Web UI or via `activator list-templates` command. After creating project under `[project-name]` dir you will have script `activator` there which itself runs `sbt`. You can use it just like usual local sbt installation.

Comment: I am stickler and I would like to have things ordered in my computers :) and wanted to have Scala and SBT installed and know where is "the installation folder" - for example to browse for Scala SDK in IntelliJ (but didnt know where the folder is, I will download brew and install scala and sbt then

Comment: Everything downloaded by brew will be in `/usr/local/Cellar` :) P.S. If my answers answered your question, please upvote and accept. Thanks.

Comment: yes they did, thanks! can I have another question now? I use Maverics on my macbook and I am afraid to update it to Yosemite since I have known many applications dont work in yosemite, especially JetBrains products. And with no Yosemite I cant download XCode. Do you think update is good idea? (btw. mac and linux catalog structure is a bit strange for windows user; now i am trying to pivot to be linux-friendly)

Comment: It's totally OK to update to 10.10 (be sure to update to 10.10.3, since there is major security issue in all previous versions), everything works fine :)